# Merge/synonymize [fluent] and [fluent-interface]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tags [fluent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluent) and [fluent-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluent-interface) both refer to the same thing.

> Fluent interface is API which allows method chaining to make code more readable.
>   (from [fluent] tag wiki)
>
> Refers to a practice of coding object-oriented APIs with the aim of improving readability of the interface, normally implemented using method chaining.
>   (from [fluent-interface] tag excerpt)

Therefore I'd suggest them being merged or turned into synonyms. As for which one to keep, I'd suggest choosing [fluent-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluent-interface) because:

- even the [fluent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluent) tag wiki always speaks of **fluent inteface** and not just **fluent** alone.
- fluent interface is more descriptive than the short form, in fact I knew right away what fluent interface was about when looking at the tag, for fluent I had to hover over it to find out that it's the same.
- fluent interfaced already got a synonym ([fluent-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluent-api))

The only thing I see speaking for fluent on the other side is that it got more questions (558 vs 380) which would block the synonym voting for now, but that should be easy to retag and doesn't pose a problem.

Comment: I'm not really sure adding any of the `fluent` tags impacts a question much.